# SQLite - DB Corrupt - btreeInitPage() Error

Tags: sqlite

The SQLite DB indicates corruption while doing operations. On running the PRAGMA integrity_check, i get the following output

```
*>>>sqlite3 prod.db
SQLite version 3.7.9 2011-11-01 00:52:41
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> PRAGMA integrity_check;
*** in database main ***
Page 21: btreeInitPage() returns error code 11
Error: database disk image is malformed
sqlite>*
```

1. Are there commands to know what caused it ?
2. Does the page number have any significance and can i get to the
   operation that caused the corruption in any manner ?

I am not so keen to retrieve the data, but am more interested in fixing the reason that keeps causing it. There were no power shutdown or similar external event that caused it, so i am suspecting the operations to be the culprit for this.

Comment: Without more to go on, I'd suggest reading through: https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html